# Iterating over an std::map, Doing something wrong, complaining of a missing operator for '=' for the iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

Here's my function:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Path& path) {
    std::map<double, glm::vec3>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = path.points.begin(); iter != path.points.end(); iter++){
        stream << "test" << "\n";
    }
}
```

And here's my error:

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\adam\skydrive\documents\proj\ray\ray\path.h    22  1   ray
```

I've never had this kind of problem before. And to be honest, I don't know where to start. I've tried a few methods of getting an iterator, including the typedef method, but the same problem persists.

Any advice?

Comment: Provided `Path::points` is of the right type, you would need a `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Path` is `const`, so you're using the `const` version of `.begin()`.  But you're trying to assign it to a mutable iterator.  Try declaring iter as `Path::const_iterator` instead.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I didn't even know that was a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Chamge this statement

```
std::map<double, glm::vec3>::iterator iter;
```

to

```
std::map<double, glm::vec3>::const_iterator iter;
```